# Mutually exclusive events in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is my layout and my javascript: http://jsfiddle.net/HRDNK/1/

Hovering over the avatar and the name, you can see that 2 popup appear. They are simply hidden and appear on Hover. I'm using a plugin called hoverIntent that simply manage the timeout.

My problem is that i cannot change this layout: Usernames and Avatars are rendered separately and my code is attached to both of them but i want the event not to trigger when it already triggered for the same user. As you can see, there are 2 ".title_list" with the same id, because the id is defined during rendering according to the user's id.

What i need is to have mutually esclusive hover events for the same user. If it's not possible, an event could exclude any other kind of .title_list event until it disappear.

I've tried to do that keeping a global list of triggered IDs, but it entered a race condition and didn't worked as intended.

Answer (score 1):

try this: http://jsfiddle.net/HRDNK/2/

basically the idea is to hide all ballon before showing the selected one.

```
if(list.children().length>0) {
   $(".title_list").hide();
   list.fadeIn(300);
}
```

of course for the sake of optimization, you should create a previous reference to `$(".title_list")` so you don't need to find those elements every time you hover a profile

Comment: simple but...brilliant. I'm gonna wait for other answers but this could do the trick.

Comment: i'm trying it but it works flawlessly and probably it's a better approach. i don't really need multiple baloons and it's aesthetically compelling.